# UI 2012 Entity Pages not writable. Error

Tags: experience-manager

We're in the process of installing Tridion UI 2012, but currently whenever we click the "Finish Editing" option we see a success message of:

**"All Changes Have Been Committed"**

However a few seconds later we see the following Error thrown:

**"Entity Pages not writable."**

So far I'm not seeing anything being logged by either my Session Preview Service or the CM. But am also not seeing anything being added into my Session Broker DB.

Is there a common cause of this generic error?

Comment: It seems to come from the Content Delivery Web Service, check the cd_webservice_conf.xml and if you have this well configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked with SDL Support, who basically just had me re-create the web.config for my preview service application. There must have been some sort of invalid character that was causing the issue.

Also for anyone using UI 2012 its worth asking for an example working service, as there are hotfixes/updated JARS in addition to the default installables they send you, which you'll need to apply as well.

Comment: I've always used the pre-built webapps and have had no issues with it so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a generic error, it's an OData webservice error. At first glance, without digging too deep, it sounds like you have not configured your odata webservice properly to allow writing to it (PUT/POST/BATCH). You do this with Tridion by configuring correctly the webservice's Ambient Data Framework and storage configurations.

An approach I always recommend is to check your application against the pre-built web applications that ship with Tridion. In your Content Delivery install folder you'll find sample web applications for preview and for the web service (for both .NET and Java) with the required web.config/web.xml configurations and all the required JAR and DLL files.

You may want to start there. Then I'd check the webservice's cd_core*.log for any error messages that may point at the issue source. It could be something as simple as the database being misconfigured.